# continue <n> not skipping <n> iterations forward in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have created a hex to ASCII converter for strings in bash. The application I'm on changes characters (anything but [0-9],[A-Z],[a-z]) , in a string to its corresponding %hexadecimal. Eg: / changes to %2F in a string

I want to retain the ASCII characters as it is. Below is my code:

```
NAME=%2fhome%40%21%23
C_NAME=""
for (( i=0; i<${#NAME}; i++ )); do
    CHK=$(echo "{NAME:$i:1}" | grep -v "\%" &> /dev/null;echo $?)
    if [[ ${CHK} -eq 0 ]]; then
       C_NAME=`echo "$C_NAME${NAME:$i:1}"`
    else
       HEX=`echo "${NAME:$i:3}" | sed "s/%//"`
       C_NAME=`echo -n "$C_NAME";printf "\x$HEX"`
       continue 2
    fi
done
echo "$C_NAME"
```

OUTPUT:

```
 /2fhome@40!21#23
```

EXPECTED:

```
  /home@!#
```

So basically the conversion is happening, but not in place. Its retaining the hex values as well, which tells me the `continue 2` statement is probably not working as I expect in my code. Any workarounds please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one loop so I assume you expected that `continue 2` skips the current and next iteration of the current loop, however, the documentation `help continue` clearly states

> continue [n]
>   [...]
>   If N is specified, resumes the Nth enclosing loop.

There is no built-in to skip the current *and also the next* iteration of the current loop, but in your case you can use `(( i += 2 ))` instead of `continue 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the structure of your script with some simplifications and corrections:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
name=%2fhome%40%21%23
c_name=""
for (( i=0; i<${#name}; i++ )); do
    c=${name:i:1}
    if [[ $c != % ]]; then
       c_name=$c_name$c
    else
       hex=${name:i+1:2}
       printf -v c_name "%s\x$hex" "$c_name"
       (( i += 2 ))    # stolen from Dudi Boy's answer
    fi
done
echo "$c_name"
```

- Always use lower case or mixed case variables to avoid the chance of name collisions with shell or environment variables
- Always use `$()` instead of backticks
- Most of the `echo` commands you use aren't necessary
- You can avoid using `sed` and `grep`
- Variables should never be included in the format string of `printf` but it can't be avoided easily here (you could use `echo -e "\x$hex"` instead though)
- You can do math inside parameter expansions
- `%` doesn't need to be escaped in your `grep` command
- You could eliminate the `$hex` variable if you used its value directly:
  `printf -v c_name "%s\x${name:i+1:2}" "$c_name"`

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoyed your exercise and decided to solve it with awk (my current study).

Hope you like it as well.

```
cat script.awk

BEGIN {RS = "%[[:xdigit:]]+"} { # redefine record separtor to RegEx (gawk specific)
        decNum = strtonum("0x"substr(RT, 2)); # remove prefix # from record separator, convert hex num to dec
        outputStr = outputStr""$0""sprintf("%c", decNum); # reconstruct output string
}
END {print outputStr}
```

The output

```
echo %2fhome%40%21%23 |awk -f script.awk
/home@!#
```